# Does IKEA have a json / XML access point for product information?

Tags: data-request, api

For a small project I would like to get the product data for [IKEA](https://ikea.com/) products. Things like dimensions, color, assembly instructions etc.

Other parts of IKEA data (product names, item number, stock level and stores) are available in an XHR call, but I can not find the product details anywhere except inside the HTML code as a json structure inside an attribute. So lots of overhead here.

Do anyone know of an IKEA API for these details ? Or know how to get access to the new [InterIkea API developer portal](https://developer.inter.ikea.com/publish) ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone has been working on one:

[Documentation on Github for Ikea API](https://github.com/vrslev/ikea-api-client)

No Idea if it works though...

Comment: The endpoints for these are relatively simple to find using browser inspections. But none of them give **item** information.  The GitHub project does not really work anymore, as IKEA has changed a few things.